# how to read byte by byte from a file

Tags: c

I want to read the 4 first bytes from a binnary file which is a song.wav type. In a .wav file the 4 first bytes must be 52-46-49-49 and I have to read them to check later if they are true.

The thing is that I have a compile arror at the fread line which says `invalid conversion from "unsigned char" to "void"` and  `initialzing argument 1 of 'size_t fread(void*,size_t,size_t,FILE*)` and i dont know what it means.

I saw in a previous topic tha this is the way that fread must be done if i want to read byte by byte. If anyone has any idea of how i can read byte by byte and store them in an array that be great. Thank you.

```
void checksong(char *argv[]){
    FILE *myfile;
    int i;
    unsigned char k[4];
    myfile=fopen(argv[2],"r");
    i=0;
    for(i=0; i<4; i++){
       fread(k[i],1,1,myfile);
    }
    for(i=0; i<4; i++){
       printf("%c\n", k[i]);
    }                                  
    return ;
}
```

Comment: use `getc()` `char` is always a byte.

Answer (score 10):

It is a single error:

> Invalid conversion from `unsigned char`to `void*` initializing argument 1 of
>
> ```
> size_t fread(void*,size_t,size_t,FILE*)
> ```

It means `k[i]` is an `unsigned char`, and not a pointer. You should use `&k[i]` or `k+i`.

However, you don't really need to read byte by byte. You can read 4 bytes, no loops involved:

```
fread(k, 4, 1, myfile);
```

Printing the numbers:

```
for (i=0; i<4; i++)
   printf("%d\n", k[i]);
```

Comment: i did it and it fixed my error,thank you.But instead of the numbers 52-46-49-49  that i should get i get some weird symbols :S

Comment: @ZoNiaC You get the numbers. just print them using %d and not %c.

Answer (score 5):

In order to read exactly one byte and store it into `k` at index `i`, you need to provide the address of element i

```
for(i=0; i<4; i++){
    fread(&k[i],1,1,myfile);
}
```

However, you'd rather read the whole 4 bytes in one go if you're interested in them 4. So no `for` loop at all, and just do:

```
fread(k,1,4,myfile);
```

It is also good practice to test the return code of `fread` (and any I/O operation for that matter) in case it fails. `man fread` for more information.

Answer (score 4):

You can use just

```
char buffer[4];
fread(buffer,1,4,myfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need not to use `fread()` Even the `fgetc()` works well. Simple coding. SImple as reading a text file.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    FILE* f = fopen("lak", "rb");
    fseek(f,0,SEEK_END);
    long lsize=0,i=0;
    lsize = ftell(f);
    rewind(f);

    while(i<lsize){
        int first = fgetc(f);
        i++;
        printf("first byte = %x\n", (unsigned)first); //you can do anything with 
                                                      //first now
    }

fclose(f);

return 0;
}
```